# C# - Joining All Lists of Lists together

Tags: c#

I have a C# app. In this C# app, I have an object that I'll call `order`. Inside of `order` is a property called `Departments`. Inside of `Departments` is a property called `Items`. I want to put all `Items` across all of the `Departments` into a `List`. Is there a more elegant solution than this:

```
var items = new List<Item>();
foreach (var department in order.Departments)
{
    foreach (var item in department.Items)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

While the above "works". It just seems like I could write it in a more condensed way. Yet, I haven't been able to figure out how.

Thanks,

Comment: Is AddRange () good enough for you?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to post this question instead of googling it first?  Or can you modify your question to show evidence that you researched and couldn't find what you were looking for?  Here's what I got when I copied your title into google: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+-+Joining+All+Lists+of+Lists+together&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: And, I'd like to point out that with a 1.6K rep, you should know how this works by now...

Comment: @rory.ap All rep earned with questions, not answers

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer -- even more reason he should know how to ask...

Comment: you can use items.AddRange(department.Items);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **SelectMany** in **Linq** for this.

```
var result = order.Departments.SelectMany(x => x.Items).ToList();
```